# I Have a DNN website, i want to prevent FOUC on it

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, dotnetnuke, fouc, dotnetnuke-8

**Problem:** I Have a **DNN** website, i want to prevent **FOUC** on it.

I created a **Zurb Foundation** skin, every time the page loads there is a Flash of unstyled content(**FOUC**), such as the menu showing all the drop-downs for a few seconds.

After many searches, i found that i just need to add this class `no-js` to the `<html>` tag as such:

```
<html class="no-js">
```

My problem is **where in DNN can I add this?**
I don't see any option to edit the `<html>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need to edit the Default.aspx file to add this, I don't know if you can do this any other way in DNN.

If you edit the default.aspx file, you will need to be sure to edit that file again if you UPGRADE DNN in the future, as your change would be lost/replaced during an upgrade.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it worked. and thank you for all your contribution to the dnn community, with the module and theme template. i would up vote if i could =]

Comment: Can you mark this as the "answer" even if you can't upvote?